# CollectionViewSource: TreeView not updating, ViewModel looking good

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, grouping

I'm trying to populate a `TreeView` in a `TestExplorerControl`:

[image: Rubberduck TestExplorer WPF control]

I never had to use a `CollectionViewSource` until now, so I used [this tutorial](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/365#.VeEay_ZVhHx) to get a grasp of how to group my `ObservableCollection<TestMethod>` in XAML, and use that grouping for my tree view - I implemented the data templates in the `<UserControl.Resources>`, because I want the flexibility to eventually allow the user change the way tests are regrouped:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="OutcomeGroupViewSource" Source="{Binding Model.Tests}">
  <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Result.Outcome" />
  </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TestMethodTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:TestMethod}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image .../>
    <TextBlock .../>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="OutcomeTemplate" DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestMethodTemplate}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image ../>
    <TextBlock ../>
    <TextBlock ../>
  </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Then I have this markup for the actual `<TreeView>`:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="2"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OutcomeGroupViewSource}, Path=View.Groups}"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OutcomeTemplate}" />
```

What's wrong with this markup, for the `TreeView` to fail updating? The ViewModel clearly has all the data I need to display (the breakpoint that was hit is on the current line, in yellow):

[image: debugger with a breakpoint in <code>TreeView_MouseDoubleClick</code> in the control's code-behind, showing a non-null <code>TestExplorerViewModel</code> context with 2 items in <code>Tests</code>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It's the `Path` of the `ItemsSource` binding in the tree view:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OutcomeGroupViewSource}, Path=View.Groups}"
```

`Path=View.Groups` satisfies IntelliSense, but is wrong.

It needs to be `Path=Groups`, **even if the designer supposedly can't resolve the property:**

[image: Path=Groups => Cannot resolve property 'Groups' in data context of type 'System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource']